# State 'cp.push' was not found in SLS

Tags: salt-stack

In salt (2018.3.0) I created the following statefile that I started to write to collect existing ssh hostkey files from minions.

```
sshHostKeys:
  cp.push:
    - path: '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub'
    - upload_path: '/'
```

Calling

```
salt-call state.apply sshHostKeys
```

I get:

```
local:
----------
          ID: sshHostKeys
    Function: cp.push
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'cp.push' was not found in SLS 'sshHostKeys'
              Reason: 'cp.push' is not available.
```

Manually calling:

```
salt-call cp.push /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
```

works just fine, the file is copied to the salt master.

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong in the state file?

Thanks Rainer

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. This should work:

```
custom function name:
  module.run:
    - name: cp.push
    - path: <<your path>>
```

See issue on github for reference:
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/42330